# If you see something, say something: Low-quality generative AI answers

Tags: discussion

This is a gentle reminder that Stack Exchange does have a temporary ban on generative AI:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

As we understand, everyone here is trying their best to create a wonderful knowledge base for the community, please be mindful of your answers.

We have noticed some low-quality, generative AI answers (and some, outright wrong).

If you see answers that are low-quality and do not help the community then please **down vote**, **flag**, or **comment** on them.

I leave you with a question that I always think about when answering questions on SE:

- Does my answer truly answer the question at hand or benefit the community or is it more noise than signal?